# Run time error: "/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc........" in VS Code while working with strings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, runtime-error, stdstring

My code is running properly in other online C++ compilers but throws an unexpected error in VS Code. Please find the bug in my code.
VS Code Version - 1.74.3

***CODE:***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    int size;
    cout << "Enter the size of your string value" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    cout << "Enter the string whose first letter has to be changed" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cin >> input[i];
    }

    input[0] = 'Z';
    cout<< "The changed string is ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << input[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**TERMINAL:**

```
    Enter the size of your string value
    4
    Enter a string whose first letter has to be changed
    moya
```

**ERROR:**

```
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libstdc++- 
v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1067: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, 
_Alloc>::reference std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[] 
(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; 
_Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference = char&; 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]: 
Assertion '__pos <= size()' failed.
```

Comment: `input` is an empty string, so you cannot iterate on its characters. You need to at least set its length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string input;` is empty so `input[i]` accesses the string out of bounds which makes your program have *undefined behavior*. You could `resize` it to `size` to make it work - or create the string with the correct size *after* you've entered what `size` you want it to have.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    int size;
    std::cout << "Enter the size of your string value\n";
    if(std::cin >> size && size > 0) {

        input.resize(size); // resize the string
        // std::string input(size, '\0'); // or create it here with the correct size

        std::cout << "Enter the string whose first letter has to be changed\n";

        for(char& ch : input) { // a simpler range-based for loop
            std::cin >> ch;
        }
        input[0] = 'Z';
        std::cout << "The changed string is ";
        std::cout << input << '\n'; // no need to loop here
    }
}
```

Comment: What could be the reason that online compilers like gdb do not throw this error?

Comment: @Ultimate When you have undefined behavior anything can happen. You can catch some of these in runtime by adding `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` when compiling.